# regex with optional capture group

Tags: regex, capture-group

I am trying to get the ammount, unit and substance out of a string using a regex. The units and substances come from a predefined list.

So:

- "2 kg of water" should return: `2, kg, water`
- "1 gallon of crude oil" should return: `1, gallon, oil`

I can achieve this with the following regex:
    `(\d*) ?(kg|ml|gallon).*(water|oil)`

The problem is that I can't figure out how to make the last capture group optional. If the substance is not in the predefined list, I still want to get the ammount and unit. So:

- "1 gallon of diesel" should return: `1, gallon` or `1, gallon, ''`

I have tried wrapping the last group in an optional non capturing group as explained here: [Regex with optional capture fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41162675/regex-with-optional-capture-fields) but with no success.

Here is the current reges in te online regex tester: https://regex101.com/r/hV3wQ3/55

Comment: Why don't you just capture `(\d+) ?(kg|ml|gallon) of (.*)` and check the list of predefined substances later?

Comment: Use `?` quantifier it matches between zero and one times. `(water|oil)?`

Comment: @S.Jovan That doesn't work. It will always fail to capture anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to use `(\d+) ?(kg|ml|gallon).*(?:(water|oil))?` and there is no way this pattern can capture `water` / `oil`. The problem is the `.*` grabs any 0+ chars other than line break chars up to the end of the string / line, and the `(?:(water|oil))?` is tried when the regex index is there, at the string end. Since `(?:(water|oil))?` can match an empty string, it matches the location at the end of the string, and the match is returned.

You may still use the capturing group as obligatory, but wrap the `.*` and the capturing group with an optional non-capturing group:

```
(\d+) ?(kg|ml|gallon)(?:.*(water|oil))?
                     ^^^             ^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tD92qp/1)

The `(?:.*(water|oil))?` matches 1 or 0 (greedily) occurrences of any 0+ chars other than line break chars (`.*`) and then either `water` or `oil`.

Comment: Nice, this works like a charm. I see how this works. But I don't get why `(\d+) ?(kg|ml|gallon).*(?:(water|oil))?` does not work. Why does that not match (water|oil) in group 3?

Comment: @JasperZelf Because the `.*` already grabbed the `water` or `oil`, and there is no need to backtrack since `(...)?` matches anything, even an empty string (a location).

Comment: That akes perfect sence. Thanks for the explanation